# Insert com quantidade massiva de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo

Olá!

Estamos trabalhando em um projeto utilizando PHP e banco de dados Mysql, no qual em determinado momento deverá ser inserido no banco uma larga escala de registros (por exemplo, entre 5 mil e 1 milhão),

No momento, a forma mais básica para obter desempenho que encontramos seria fazendo um insert único.

```sql
INSERT INTO clientes(id, nome, cpf, email, telefone)
VALUES (1, "Lorem Ipsum", "09941752727", "loremipsum@lorem.com", "1140028922"),
       (1, "Lorem Ipsum", "09941752729", "loremips@lorem.com", "1140028922")...
```

O problema desse método é que ele não verifica se o registro já foi inserido anteriormente e também não nos permite verificar o andamento da inserção, para podermos exibir na tela o quanto falta para ser concluído.

**Há alguma forma de solucionar esses problemas e ainda assim obter um alto desempenho na inserção dos dados?**

Comment: Insere com `bulk` em uma tabela temporaria e crie uma `procedure` pra ler a tabela e fazer o `insert/update`

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda amigo, demorei um pouco para implementar porque sou inexperiente no assunto, mas acho que por fim entendi os benefícios de fazer dessa forma. Apenas uma dúvida quanto ao procedure, após ler a tabela o insert/update seria igual ao insert com bulk anterior?

Comment: Então, se estiver com dificuldades, edita sua pergunta com o que você tentou até o momento e explique onde está travado para que possamos ajudar :)